# Is there an easy way to find the type of a DICOM tag?

Tags: dicom, pydicom

For creating an anonymization/de-identification tool I would like to delete/overwrite all tags/attributes from the DICOM file that are not necessary. I've searched around the internet, but have not found a clear list of which tags are mandatory for a DICOM file.

I found out that there are multiple types, type 1 is mandatory, type 2 must at least be an empty string and type 3 can just be deleted. But so far I have not found an easy list online with all tags and their types. Does anyone have list of tags and types or a list of mandatory tags for DICOM file?

Answer (score 5):

The mandatory attributes (given by their tags) depend on the SOP Class of the DICOM file.

- read the Media Storage SOP Class UID (0002,0002) from the File Meta Information (meta header)
- in the [DICOM standard](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part04/sect_B.5.html), locate the IOD correspondent to the SOP Class UID (e.g. "1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.1" = Computed Radiography Image Storage)
- the [IOD specification](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part03/sect_A.2.3.html) lists the mandatory and optional modules (e.g. Patient Module, General Image Module, etc). The modules marked with **M** are mandatory, **C**=conditional, **U**=optional (user option)
- each module lists the mandatory and optional attributes (e.g. the Patient module includes the patient name, the patient ID, sex, etc). Attributes marked with **1** are mandatory, **2**=mandatory but can be empty, **3**=optional, **1C**=mandatory if some conditions are satisfied, **2C**=mandatory but can be empty if some conditions are satisfied

Comment: While the answer seems to quote valid parts of the DICOM standard, this answer misses the original poster goal: writing an anonymization/de-identification tool. In particular the tool should handle attribute with PHI (which is out side the scope of PS 3.3).

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice Presentation about "De-Identification" by David Clunie here: https://www.dclunie.com/papers/D2_1045_Clunie_Deidentification.pdf

The concepts presented went into the [DICOM Standard Part 15, Annex E - De-Identification](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part15.html#chapter_E)

Answer (score 1):

The current list of attributes to handle for a valid de-identifier is clearly described in the DICOM standard PS 3.15:

- [Attribute Confidentiality Profiles](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part15/chapter_E.html)

In particular see the table:

- [Table E.1-1. Application Level Confidentiality Profile Attributes](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part15/chapter_E.html#table_E.1-1)

As a side pay special attention to the private tags, as described in the following profile:

- [Retain Safe Private Option](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part15/sect_E.3.10.html)

For historical reference, you should also pay attention that the DICOM standard has greatly changed since the 2008 edition:

- ftp://medical.nema.org/medical/dicom/2008/08_15pu.pdf

Some tool (eg. [gdcmanon](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/gdcmanon.html)) implements the old section PS 3.15 / E.1 / Basic Application Level Confidentiality Profile (Implementation of E.1.1 De-identify & E.1.2 Re-identify).

Finally, DicomCleaner should give you an idea of what a quality implementation looks like:

- [How to use DicomCleaner](https://www.dclunie.com/pixelmed/software/webstart/DicomCleanerUsage.html)

---

The original wording of the question: "I would like to delete/overwrite all tags/attributes from the DICOM file that are not necessary" seems to be in conflict with the definition of "de-identification". So either the question is poorly formulated, or you are missing the fact that Type 1 attribute may contain [Protected Health Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_health_information).